# Wrong clang-tidy warning about static global lambda variables?

Tags: c++, lambda, clang-tidy

Provided the following code, in the global scope, clang-tidy gives no warning:

```
auto test = []{};
```

However, when doing the following, it does:

```
#include <tuple>

auto test = []{
    std::tuple t{1, 2, 3};
};
```

> ```
> <source>:3:6: warning: initialization of 'test' with static storage duration may throw an exception that cannot be caught [cert-err58-cpp]
> auto test = []{
>      ^
>
> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../include/c++/8.2.0/tuple:646:19: note: possibly throwing constructor declared here
>         constexpr tuple(_UElements&&... __elements)
>                   ^
> ```

Marking the lambda as `noexcept` doesn't help.

However, I don't see why that would be a problem. The exception could only theorically happen when *invoking* the lambda, wouldn't it?

The following code does not cause the warning to appear:

```
auto test = [] {
    throw 0;
};
```

Is clang-tidy wrong, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Clang-Tidy warning is about the construction of the global variable, not about the `operator()` of such class does. Hence, this looks like a false positive.

I would make the variable `constexpr` as it can't change during the lifetime of your program. That should as well suppress the warning as well as constexpr can't be done of such an exception is thrown.

PS: You can log bugs for Clang-Tidy at bugs.llvm.org

Comment: Actually... With `constexpr` it *still* actually warns. I will report it to LLVM then, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a second bug :)

Comment: Reported both: [the lambda issue](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39777) and [the constexpr issue](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39778)